# CSS 3 rotateY() and rotateX() not working as expected

Tags: css

I am trying out the new features in css3 while i found that rotateY() and rotateX() is not giving expected results. 
I have a single div in the page

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

This is the css

```
#element{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
```

[image: This is the expected result]

[image: This is what i get]

The blue shape is what i want and yellow is what i get

Comment: You may provide a perspective: `transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(45deg);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a container and give it `perspevtive: 500px` to get a 3D looking effect.

```css
#container {
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}
#element {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to complete your [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) and [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) style rule:

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgbdq0oL/)

```css
body{
    -webkit-perspective:200px;
    -moz-perspective:200px;
    perspective:200px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin:center 400px /* 300px + 200px/2 */;
    -moz-perspective-origin:center 400px /* 300px + 200px/2 */;
    perspective-origin:center 400px /* 300px + 200px/2 */;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
#element{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:center;
    -moz-transform-origin:center;
    transform-origin:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

The parent of `#element` (not necessary `<body>`) has to have:

- [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) so your browser knows how "far" the viewport is from `#element`, and render the rotation effect accordingly;
- [`perspective-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective-origin) so your browser knows where the "center" of your viewport is;

The [`transform-style:preserve-3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) do not seem to be necessary in this specific case, and [IE doesn't support this feature yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d). I just added it out of habit.

Comment: Really? Giving `perspective` to `body` is a horrible idea.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I think I have pointed out that it's the parent of `#element` who needs `perspective`, and I emphasized its not necessary `<body>`.